# Why is a C string not always equivalent to an array of chars?

Tags: arrays, c, string

Given that a C string is a null terminated array of chars :

```
const char str1[] = {"abc"};
const char str2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
const char str3[] = {97, 98, 99, '\0'};
```

are the same.

So why is it possible to generate an array of strings like this:

```
const char * str_arr[] = {"abc", "ABCD"};
const char * str_arr[] = { str1, str2, str3 };
```

but not like this? :

```
const char * str_arr[] = { {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0'} };
fatal error: excess elements in scalar initializer
```

Comment: How would an array of characters turn into an array of *character pointers*?

Comment: `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` is NOT an array. It is an initializer list.

Comment: `const char * str = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};` makes no sense. So why do you think `const char * str_arr[] = { {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0'} };` does?

Comment: You also have the opposite, `const char str[3] = "abc";` which is an array of chars that is not a string (because it is not null terminated.

Comment: @BoP I don't think that is right, the null termination is added automatically. It does not even compile: `fatal error: initializer-string for char array is too long` - which is solved by changing the 3 to a 4.

Comment: @John - That error message looks like what clang would give you for C++, but not for C. Different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const char str1[] = {"abc"};
const char str2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
const char str3[] = {97, 98, 99, '\0'};
```

These work because of rules in C 2018 6.7.9 about how initializers are processed:

- In `const char str1[] = {"abc"};`, a string literal is given to initialize an array of `const char`. 6.7.9 14 says “An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF–8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.”
- In `const char str2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};`, a list of `int` values (character constants have type `int`) is given to initialize an array. 6.7.9 17 tells us these are used to initialize the subobjects of the array (its elements) in order.

```
const char * str_arr[] = {"abc", "ABCD"};
const char * str_arr[] = { str1, str2, str3 };
```

For these:

- In `const char * str_arr[] = {"abc", "ABCD"};`, a list of string literals is used to initialize an array of pointers. Note that this is not **a** string literal enclosed in braces; it is **two** string literals, so it does not match the rule above. There is no special rule for string literals being used to initialize an array of pointers instead of an array of character type, so it is handled using other rules of C, and the two string literals initialize two elements of the array. A string literal designates an array of characters. 6.3.2.1 3 says that when an array is not the operand of `sizeof`, the operand of unary `&`, or a string literal used to initialize an array, it is converted to a pointer to its first element. So each of those two arrays, the ones designated by the string literals, is converted to a pointer to its first element, and those pointers become the initial values of `str_arr`.
- In `const char * str_arr[] = { str1, str2, str3 };`, `str1`, `str2`, and `str3` are arrays. As just above, they are automatically converted to pointers to their first elements, and those pointers are used to initialize `str_arr`.

```
const char * str_arr[] = { {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0'} };
```

For this, each element of `str_arr` is a `const char *`, and the initializer offered for it is `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}`. There is no rule in C that a `const char *` can be initialized with a list of `int` values in braces. When `{'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` appears in the initializers, it does not have any special meaning as an array. It is just a list of values. How that list of values is processed depends on the context of the initialization. If there were an array to fill in, the values in the list could be used to fill in the array elements. But there is no array, and there is no rule that says this list of values is made into an array and a pointer to that array is made.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful and exhaustive answer. It took me a while to absorb it and it is becoming clear to me that I sometimes struggle with pointers (and their syntax) as soon as it goes beyond a single pointer to a single variable. Also the subtleties of string literals and initialisation were not clear to me. I should probably get a good reference (book or website) to advance myself in C, but have not been able to find one yet that is at the right level...

Answer (score 0):

You actually can, if you cast them to `const char []`:

```
const char * str_arr[] = { (const char []){'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}, (const char []){'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0'} };
```

You can't initialise a type of `const char *` with an array of `char`s (because where's the pointer?), but you can initialise a type of `const char[]` with that, and have it *decay* into `const char *`.

Comment: That's not a cast, it is a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) and its associated *initializer-list*. Care must be taken with regards to the lifetime of these objects.

Comment: This answer lacks nuance. You can certainly _use_ an array to initialize a pointer, e.g., `char a[] = "abc"; char *ap = a;`. Here `a` is an array (initialized by a string literal) used to initialize `ap` (initialized by a pointer to the first element of `a`). `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }` is not an array in OP code or in this answer; `(const char[]){ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' }` _is_ an array by virtue of being a compound literal, but there is no array being "cast" or even used to initialize an anonymous array. `{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0\ }` is just an initializer list.